# Angular app not rendering in ie 11 and giving SecurityError and SyntaxError

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

I developed application using angular. It is rendering perfectly in chrome and Firefox. But, when I run it in ie-11, I am facing so many issues.

I have solved many issues by adding polyfills in polyfills.ts. Still I am facing few other issues. Please look at the screenshot below.

[IE error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJSaR.png)

Here is my polyfills,

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';

// import 'whatwg-fetch';

/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 **/
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 */

 // (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
 // (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
 // (window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames

 /*
 * in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 * with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 */
(window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */

import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
```

Please help me solve this issue. 
Thank you...

Comment: Did you run `npm install --save classlist.js` and `npm install --save web-animations-js`?

Comment: please try to add this polyfills import 'core-js/es7/object'; import 'core-js/es7/array'; in polyfills.ts file may help to solve the issue. Ref: https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/1001

Comment: Try to run `npm install --save babel-polyfill` and add `import 'babel-polyfill';` in polyfills.ts file.

Comment: After installing, npm install --save babel-polyfill, I imported that, then I'm getting  "Cannot find module 'neo-async' Error: Cannot find module 'neo-async' " error.

Comment: Are you installing async globally? Try `npm install neo-async`.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to polyfills.ts

```
import 'core-js/es7/object';
import 'core-js/es7/array';
```

Answer (score 1):

For this problem make sure that you have enable all the required import in the `polyfills.ts` and this file is connected into `angular.json`

And add the following to the file:

```
import 'core-js/es7/object';
import 'core-js/es7/array';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an IE browser problem, you can fix it by following this link https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/1001
For core-js/es7/array you need to use "core-js": "~2.5.0"